# Unity3D iOS plugin using ObjectiveC sources to instantiate classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I would like to know if it is possible to have a Unity iOS plugin made from the sources (.h .m) that allows the instantation of classes and not only calling static methods; and guidance about how to proceed.

I have a java library that has been converted to C# and ObjectiveC with the idea of producing Android, Windows and iOS plugins for unity to later make a transparent layer that will be used in my scene scripts.

Answer (score 0):

**Calling Unity C# from native code:**

```
UnitySendMessage("UnityFactory", "CreateObject", "Message");
```

The "UnityFactory" could be implemented as factory to create new object. The "Message" could be the payload for the new object in json format.

**Calling native (.mm not .m because .mm is c/c++ compatible) from Unity:**

You have to use a static method but only one.

```
extern "C" {
  void NativeSendMessage("NativeFactory", "CreateObject", "Message");
}
```

Does the same as the UnitySendMessage...

If you need more flexibility then add more functions to the Factory. In my sample there is only a "CreateObject" but if you don't want to create an object you could add a RouteToObject function ( but of course you need a registry mechanism and the object id in the "Massage" json ).

**iOS GUI overlay** 
I'am not sure if this is relevant to you too but you can overlay the unity-view with UIView's. You have to look for "unity application controller subclassing"